# Whatsapp notifications on iPhone 6 plus

Tags: ios, iphone, whatsapp

Hello Community Members,

I am using iOS device (iPhone) with latest iOS version.

When I get message from one of my contacts and screen is locked, WhatsApp shows that I got message from name (name it uses is set by user, and not as saved in my contacts)

Example: If I get a message from my brother, whose contact is saved on my device as "Bro" and if screen is locked, it reads 1 message from Mr. Mehta (which is set by my brother as his display name on WhatsApp)

Anyone facing same issue, or it's just me. If yes, any solution for same.

Comment: Using WhatsApp has nothing to do with programming. Please don't post again without reading the FAQs.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming, but how to use an Apple device. It might be more suitable for [apple.se].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes... whenever the screen is in lock mode, you get the username that THEY set, not what you have them as. As far as I can muster, this cannot be changed.

Comment: Can this be changed if we jail break our iphone?

Comment: I honestly don't see what Jailbreaking will do at all. The app must receive the username via a push and that's what is sent. Jailbreaking I can't see changing this.